# Disable html-helper-mode by default in Aquamacs to edit HTML

Tags: html, emacs, elisp, aquamacs

Aquamacs has a default `html-helper-mode`to edit `.html` files that has weird behaviors. I would like to switch back to regular `html-mode` by default.

I read that I needed to change the  `magic-mode-alist` to do so.
From what I understand from the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#index-magic_002dmode_002dalist-1651), adding this to my `.emacs` should do the deal:

```
(setq magic-mode-alist '(("\\.html" . html-mode)))
```

Unfortunately it does not change anything.
I read [elsewhere](http://formyfriendswithmacs.com/aquamacs.html) that setting it to `nil` should work but it did not either.

Any idea what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [the page I linked](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html), the first variable to modify is `magic-mode-alist` which has precedence on `auto-mode-alist`.

I just added a value at the beginning of the list of matches using the exact same regular expression that was in `magic-mode-alist` pointing to `html-helper-mode`:

```
(add-to-list 'magic-mode-alist 
    '("\\(?:<\\?xml\\s +[^>]*>\\)?\\s *<\\(?:!--\\(?:[^-]\\|-[^-]\\)*-->\\s *<\\)*\\(?:!DOCTYPE\\s +[^>]*>\\s *<\\s *\\(?:!--\\(?:[^-]\\|-[^-]\\)*-->\\s *\<\\)*\\)?[Hh][Tt][Mm][Ll]"
        . html-mode))
```

Works like a charm. Enjoy Aquamacs without whacky `html-helper-mode`.

Comment: It's 2018 and this is still an heroic answer IMO.  I opted for [`web-mode`](http://web-mode.org) over `html-mode`.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`magic-mode-alist` looks at the contents of the file. You want to edit `auto-mode-alist`, which looks at filenames. See the [same page you linked](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html) for a discussion of that variable.

And you don't want to just set it to a value, because it will already have some values in it. Use the function `add-to-list`, as follows:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html\\'" . html-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes a lot of sense but I don't understand why I did not work. I tried removing the former value as well to force the new value adding `(delete '("\\.html$" . html-helper-mode) auto-mode-alist)` but it did not work either though I could check that there was not any link to `html-helper-mode` in `auto-mode-alist`. There must be a place where aquamacs overrides this setting but I can't find where. (you miss a parenthesis in your line ;) )

Comment: Ok, magic-mode-alist has precedence on auto-mode-alist, I need to add a match there before. I am getting closer. I'll post the final solution. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for sending me in the right direction, I posted the working solution below.